# Assigning elements in a numpy array of zeros

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to draw a "one" on a numpy array `np.zeros((28, 28))` by assigning certain rows and columns to 255. I have written the following code:

```
one = np.zeros((28, 28))
one[12:15][5:23] = 255
```

The output I'm getting after this is a simple array of zeros with no changes. Can anyone please explain this strange behavior?

**Bonus**

If you interchange `[12:15]` and `[5:23]`, rows 17 to 19 are filled with 255.

Comment: Can I ask what you were actually trying to do with this code?

Comment: I was not at all doing something serious, just trying to create my own unique digits to know how the neural net works.

Comment: Updated to address your edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation you are using is valid but does something very different from what you expect. Numpy indices consist of tuples, one element per dimension. The index you are trying to get looks like this

```
one[(12:15, 5:23)] = 255
```

For convenience, python allows you to remove the parentheses, so almost everyone would write

```
one[12:15, 5:23] = 255
```

It's useful to remember that that's just shorthand for a tuple containing slice objects, because sometimes you have to build it externally.

Let's look at what your original index actually does. Each bracket expression in python is a call to `__getitem__` or `__setitem__`. Your index can be rewritten as

```
view = one[12:15]  # __getitem__
view[5:23] = 255   # __setitem__
```

You are allowed to pass in a tuple that is shorter than the number of dimensions. In that case, the leading dimensions are indexed, and all the remaining dimensions are implicit grabbed in their entirety. What that means practically is that you are effectively doing

```
view = one[12:15, :]
view[5:23, :] = 255
```

`view` is a slice of rows 12-14, inclusive. It is a 3x28 array. In keeping with python convention, numpy allows you to assign to indices past the end of an array, silently doing nothing. `view` has only 3 rows, so assigning rows 5-22 does nothing.

Hopefully this makes the situation in your edit clear. If you grab rows 5-22, you get an 18x28 slice of `ones`, offset by 5 rows. This slice has rows 12-14, so you end up setting rows 12+5, 13+5 and 14+5 in the original array.

Answer (score 5):

With `one[12:15][5:23]` you first select rows from 12 to 15 (3 rows), then you select rows 5 to 23 from these 3 rows. These rows do not exists, then you do not update anything.

The syntax for updating rows 12 to 15 crossed with columns 5 to 23 is

```
one[12:15,5:23] = 255
```

Comment: Why though? The syntax is not invalid at all. Understanding why one works but the other doesn't is more important than just plugging it.

Comment: with `one[12:15]` you select rows from 12 to 15, then you obtain 3 rows. Then you add `[5:23]` to select rows 5 to 23 from these 3 rows. These rows do not exists, then you do not update anything.
The syntax for updating rows 12 to 15 crossed with columns 5 to 23 is `one[12:15,5:23]`

Comment: If anyone gets the answer, please do post it here.

Comment: What don't you understand in my last comment?

Comment: Is  `one[12:15,5:23]` predefined or something for numpy? Each [ ] means selecting a new row and column pair?

Comment: @jpl. You should update your answer. I posted an answer without seeing your reply. Sorry, I'm on mobile

Comment: @Yashvander. I've posted a detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

To expand on jpl's answer: your syntax would be correct if you were dealing with python's list data structure. But you are dealing with numpy's ndarray data structure so it is not and jpl syntax is correct.

Comment: The syntax is perfectly valid. Why is it not working?

Comment: It is not working because it is operating on a numpy array and is therefore invalid, if it was operating on a python list it would be valid.

Comment: `x[slice1][slice2]` works with both lists and arrays.  Python calculates `temp=x[slice1]`, and follows with `temp1 = temp[sllice2]`.  A slice of a list is still a list; a slice of an array has the same number of dimensions.  `x[i][j]` for scalar indices is different, with a reduction in nesting or dimensionality at each step.